# Render assetics from custom form fields inone place

Tags: symfony, assets

I have small problem. I have created many custom form fields, each field add necessary css/js file.

In this example I name this field "testType".

I add it in formTheme:

```
{% stylesheets
            'plugins/test.min.css'filter='cssrewrite' output='compiled/css/test.css' %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
<input id="{{ id }}" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} type="{{ type }}" value="{{ value is not empty ? value : '' }}">
```

Everything work fine but if I will use many times this same field. They will be added many times.

How can I write some extra plugin to add it in form_start or form_end only one time and unique css/js files?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `form_start block`.

```
{% block form_start %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% set method = method|upper %}
    {% if method in ["GET", "POST"] %}
        {% set form_method = method %}
    {% else %}
        {% set form_method = "POST" %}
    {% endif %}

    {% stylesheets
        'plugins/test.min.css'filter='cssrewrite' output='compiled/css/test.css' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}

    <form method="{{ form_method|lower }}" class="form-horizontal" 
         action="{{ action }}"{% for attrname, attrvalue in attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}{% if multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %}>
    {% if form_method != method %}
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="{{ method }}" />
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_start %}
```

Read more about form customization here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Comment: Thank you Paweł for your response.

Your response is only a part of my problem.

I want to import only files which I need. So if the specified field is used in my form I have to save it. Maybe in global variable and next render only needed files. But I cant find how.

Comment: maybe you can create special block for this element and override it every time with values? Then at end you will have it there just once.

Comment: I have tried to set variable in form_start and render it in form_end but variables from block disapear in another block. I have tested global twig variable too but situation is this same. Changes are visible only in block where I changed it. So the question is how to save information from block and show it in another block?